# How to resolve CORS error in python flask when connected to angular 6

Tags: python, angular, python-3.x, flask

My Flask application has a Agular6 front end. whenever i am executing the below code , i am getting the below error.
(Angular and flask are connecting over a local network)

```
import flask
import main_function as mf
from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/api/v1.0/second_page/<ticker>/<doc_type>/<selection>',methods=['GET'])
def get_aggregated_past_data_for_selection(ticker,selection,doc_type):
    num_iter = 0
    new_ticker_flag = True

    if ticker and doc_type and selection:
        final_value_dict = mf.combine_past_data(ticker,doc_type,selection,num_iter,new_ticker_flag,calling_from='api')
        response = flask.jsonify(final_value_dict)
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
        return response

    else:
        return flask.jsonify({"Error": “Some fields missing. Please try againr."})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This happens when multiple request are coming one after the other.  For eg. if 5 requests come 2 or 3 requests will be success and others will fail.
**Is there a limit to the number of request which is being send to flask?**, or can it be because of a new request coming in before the previous one execute?

> `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.14:5000/api/v1.0/second_page/AAPL/10-K/24_2_5' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally, the error was because multiple requests coming from front end 'at the same time', one after the other, before my `get_aggregated_past_data_for_selection` function could execute and return the response for each request.
**Solved:**  by ***adding a delay of 100ms*** after each request, at the front end.

Comment: how you did that